# RegExp variable gives boolean result, but giving variable name in array instead of boolean value

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, boolean

I need an array with the boolean values, but instead, it gives me the variable name.

Here is a simplistic example:

I declare variable to check for match to other data, gives boolean results.

```
var usatest = new RegExp("USA").test(continent);  //this gives true result
var canadatest = new RegExp("Canada").test(continent); //this gives false result
var mexicotest = new RegExp("Mexico").test(continent); //this gives false result
```

create array from the variables:

```
var testArray = 'usatest,canadatest,mexicotest'.split(",");
```

so testArray is `['usatest','canadatest','mexicotest']` but want `[ true, false, false ]`
tested other ways:

```
var testArray1 = [{}];
testArray1[0] = usatest; 
testArray1[1] = canadatest;
testArray1[2] = mexicotest;
```

result is array `[ true , false, false]`.

So try to substitute the name with the array value (would allow me to use a for loop for a long list)

```
var testArray2 - [{}];
testArray2[0] = usatest;
testArray2[1] = testArray1[1];
testArray2[2] = testArray1[2];
```

would expect to get `[ true, false, false]` but get `[true , 'canadatest', 'mexicotest']`

why does using `testArray1[1]` in the second array return the variable name and not the boolean value?  And maybe that will answer why `testArray` does not return boolean values either. What am I missing?

Thanks,
Doc

Comment: continent is undefined

Comment: Are you sure you didn't use `testArray[1]` and `testArray[2]`? That's the array you created earlier from `split()`.

Comment: Try using more meaningful variable names, you'll be less likely to use the wrong one.

Comment: `testArray` is the result of a [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) operation, so of course it's an array of strings.

Comment: Are you trying to use the strings in `testArray` to get the values of the corresponding variables? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript

Comment: The simplest is possibly `let arr = ["USA", "Canada", "Mexico"].map(x => new RegExp(x).test(continent))`

Comment: @derpirscher I was about to post that as an answer. Why don't you do the honors?

Answer (score 0):

For your first attempt, `testArray` is the result of a [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) operation, so of course it's an array of `strings`.

For your third attempt: Are you sure you used the correct array to get your data from, because `testArray1[1]` is a boolean, there is no way, that `testArray1[1]` will give you `canadatest`

The simplest in your usecase is possibly (assuming `continent` is defined accordingly)

```
let arr = ["USA", "Canada", "Mexico"].map(x => new RegExp(x).test(continent))
```

Ie, create an array from the results of the `RegExp.test` function directly ...

Dynamically access to variables (ie when their name is stored in another variable) is a real pain in JS, especially if they are not living in the global `window` context.

Comment: derpirscher,

Thanks, this worked doing the array this way.  But the answer to the question was what you said earlier.  I was putting a string into the array.  As Akalanka said instead of testArray = 'usatest,canadatest,mexicotest'.split(","); I should have used testarray= [usatest, canadatest,mexicotest] which also worked.  Thanks for the help.
Doc

Answer (score 0):

I think you can correct this step
create an array from the variables:

```
var testArray = [usatest, canadatest, mexicotest];
```

[image]